# Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. (Every 10 sec in my Event Log)

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I got the following INFO in my event log every 10 sec, any idea what does it mean? and why getting this info?

Windows 2003, managed by 1 user (me) and I only have the account.

Event Log Message:

"Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. The session was forcibly terminated."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have RDP running on 3389 without restrictions then you are probably getting hammered. Set your router to redirect some other port to 3389, let say 7789 to 3389. You can even change the default port via windows registry from 3389 to something else. Also, consider using Windows Firewall to narrow IP addresses (or even MAC addresses) that should have access to RDP. Finally, consider using VPN and don't keep any RDP ports open. Furthermore, check the logon type in the event. You should be looking for logon type 2 (interactive via console) and type 10 (via RDP protocol). Other logon types are for accessing shares etc (refer to Microsoft page for more http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)